# How to add 'routerLink' dynamically?

Tags: html, angular, angular2-routing

I'm using Angular 4, and i want to append some static html that is comming from database. Content have some 'anchor tag'  which is hold routerLink attribute. When i show in template via [innerHTML], it's removing 'routeroutlet' attribute from anchor tag. How it is possible to add 'routerLink'? Which is work properly for navigation page?

My content is given below, which is comming from database:

```
<div class="row banner-item">
          <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink] = "['/category']"><img alt="banner-image" class="banner-image" src="assets/images/banner-img1.jpg"/></a>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 banner-image">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink] = "['/category']"><img alt="banner-image" class="banner-image" src="assets/images/banner-img3.jpg"/></a>
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" [routerLink] = "['/category']"><img alt="banner-image" class="banner-image" src="assets/images/banner-img2.jpg"/></a>
          </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are missing most relevant details. Please include these in the body of the question, which you can change by "editing" it.